# Help in proving the dimension of the symmetric linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I'm trying to prove that the set $$S=\{A \in \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R}^N) | A^*=A\}$$
ie the symmetric linear maps in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is a vector subspace of $\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R}^N)$ of dimension $d=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. I am aware of the intuition that if a matrix is symmetric, the upper triangle is enough to determine it; and there are $d$ elements in that triangle. But I was hoping to arrive at that result in a "matrix free way", and was wondering if anyone had some insight on how to think on those terms.

So, what I did was, using inspiration from the matrix case, I chose a basis for $\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R}^N)$ in the linear maps that assign the $i$-th basis vector the $j$-th basis vector, that is $$\pi_{ij}: \mathbb{R}^N \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N \\
\pi_{ij}(e_k)=\delta_k^i e_j$$
But I'm unsure of how to proceed. I've tried handling the $N=2,3$ for matrices and I thought maybe what I had to do was to figure out how to build symmetric basis from the $\pi_{ij}$, in a systematic way for all $N$. But something tells me that probably won't be fruitful. There must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Choosing a basis seems hardly “matrix-free.”

Comment: @TedShifrin by matrix free I just mean something which doesnt rely on "counting the upper triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove $S$ is a subspace, you need to show

1. It's a sub**set**. That's pretty easy in this case
2. It's closed under addition and scalar multiplication

Now I'm not sure of your matrix-free definition of "symmetric".

I personally like saying that a transformation $Z$ is symmetric if for all $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$, we have
$$
Z(x) \cdot y = x \cdot Z(y)
$$
where $\cdot$ is the inner product on your space (in this case, the standard "dot product" on $\mathbb R^n$).

So suppose that $T$ and $U$ are in $S$. Then for any $x,y$, we have
$$
T(x) \cdot y = x \cdot T(y)\\
U(x) \cdot y = x \cdot U(y)
$$
and we'd like to show that
$$
(T+U)x \cdot y = x \cdot (T+U)y
$$
Fortunately, by the definition of addition of functions, we have
\begin{align}
(T+U)x \cdot y 
&= (T(x) + U(x)) \cdot y \\
&= T(x) \cdot y + U(x)\cdot y & \text{ by bilinearity of the inner product} \\
&= x \cdot T(y) + x\cdot U(y) & \text{ by our two hypotheses} \\
&= x \cdot (T(y) +  U(y)) & \text{ bilinearity again} \\
&= x \cdot (T +  U)(y) & \text{ def'n of addition of functions.} \\
 \end{align}

The proof for closure under scalar multiplication is similar, and we're done.

---

What about dimensions? For that, the easiest proof seems to be to select a basis $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ of $\mathbb R^n$ -- the standard basis works fine. Let $T_{ij}$, where $i \ne j$, send all $b_k$ to zero except for $k = i, j$, and let it swap $b_i$ and $b_j$. Let $S_{i}$ send all $b_k$ to zero except $b_i$, which is sent to itself. That's a list of $n(n-1)/2 + n$ elements of the space of symmetric transforms. It takes a little work to show that they're linearly independent, but don't bother doing that.

Instead, consider the transformations $R_{ij}$ (for $i \ne j$) that send all $b_k$ to zero, except that $R_{ij} b_i = -b_j$ and $R_{ij} b_j = -b_i$. That gives you another $n(n-1)/2$ elements of the space of (all) linear maps. That space has dimension $n^2$, with a basis $Q_{ij}$ that takes $b_k$ to zero for all $k \ne i$, and takes $b_i$ to $b_j$. (In this case, $i$ and $j$ could be equal).

Now observe that for $i \ne j$, we have
$$
Q_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} ( R_{ij} + T_{ij})
$$
and that for $i = j$, we have
$$
Q_{ii} = S_{ii}
$$
Hence the span of the $Q$s lies in the span of the $R$s and $T$s and $S$s, so that the collection of all $R$s, $T$s and $S$s is a spanning set for $L(R^n, R^n)$. But it's also a set with $n^2$ elements, so it's a **basis**.  The $R$s and $T$s together span the set of symmetric transformations (this needs a little proof), so its dimension is $n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: It seems to me that $Q=\frac{1}{2}(T-R) $ for i diff than j no? Because otherwise Q sends $b_i$ to zero doesn't it? Aside from that, thank you for your answer. I'll try to prove that the R and Ts span the symmetric linear maps by myself

Comment: Also, I think it is not the Rs and Ts that span the symmetric linear maps, but the Ss and Ts right? otherwise the dimension would be n(n-1), and also its what makes sense in the matrix analogy

Comment: Yes, both these comments seem correct. I just don't have time to edit right now.